# Force recalculate svg text size

Tags: javascript, svg, text, tspan

I'm appending a `tspan` to a `text` node but the browser isn't recalculating the new size/box

JS code:

```
var result = document.querySelector('#result');
var result_delayed = document.querySelector('#result_delayed');

var text = document.querySelector('text');
var tspan = document.createElement('tspan');
tspan.setAttribute('x', '0');
tspan.setAttribute('dy', '0');
tspan.innerText = 'text';
text.appendChild(tspan);

var box = text.getBBox();

result.innerHTML = box.width + ', ' + box.height;
```

It always returns `0, 0` which means the size isn't recalculated after the append

How to force recalc in this case?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5ezpzqtt/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- SVG elements must be created using createElementNS
- innerText is not a function present on SVG elements. You can use textContent instead, which also works on HTML elements.

```js
var result = document.querySelector('#result');

var text = document.querySelector('text');
var tspan = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'tspan');
tspan.setAttribute('x', '0');
tspan.setAttribute('dy', '0');
tspan.textContent = 'text';
text.appendChild(tspan);

var box = text.getBBox();

result.innerHTML = box.width + ', ' + box.height;
```

```html
<div id="result">
result
</div>

<svg width="0" height="0">
  <text font-size="72" font-family="Arial" fill="#000" x="0" y="0"></text>
</svg>
```

Comment: This solved the issue, it works great even on IE11. Thank  you very much!